# How can I run many python scripts at once?

Tags: python, cmd, module, pycharm

I'm working on some python scripts using PyCharm. Running scripts from PyCharm works fine, but I tried bundling them up with a batch file and cmd just goes nuts:

```
    C:\Users\White Python\Desktop\Fran\theconfluence\graphs\leaderboard>python htmlcreator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htmlcreator.py", line 4, in <module>
    w = open(str(Path(__file__).parents[2]) + "/week.txt", "r")
  File "C:\Users\White Python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 617, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError(idx)
IndexError: 2

C:\Users\White Python\Desktop\Fran\theconfluence\graphs\leaderboard>cd ..\retention

C:\Users\White Python\Desktop\Fran\theconfluence\graphs\retention>python creategraph.py
['C:\\Users\\White Python\\Desktop\\Fran\\theconfluence\\graphs\\retention', 'C:\\Users\\White Python\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python
\\Python38-32\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Users\\White Python\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\White Python\
\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\White Python\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32', 'C:\\Us
ers\\White Python\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "creategraph.py", line 9, in <module>
    w = open(str(Path(__file__).parents[2]) + "/week.txt", "r")
  File "C:\Users\White Python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 617, in __getitem__
    raise IndexError(idx)
IndexError: 2
```

Other scripts which did not require importing modules worked fine. Help!

Comment: Have you installed scipy?

Comment: Yes, pip list shows scipy.

Comment: It says "Current interpreter: C:\Users\White Python\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"

Comment: Actually, I fixed the scipy problem. My path was messed up and python was running from some folder I downloaded instead of the actual python folder. I'm editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your html creator a script? Or more like module? If it's like a module the try:

```
python -m htmlcreator
```

Comment: Not sure what's the difference. Anyway, here's what I get when running it like that: `(ModuleNotFoundError: __path__ attribute not found on 'htmlcreator' while trying to find 'htmlcreator.py')`

Comment: Wait! It actually worked, but only if I remove the ".py". So I'm marking this as solved. THANKS!